# Where do I find details of Ubuntu Firefox "install" offers?

Tags: firefox

When I visit some sites (so far Tweetdeck, Tumblr, Launchpad, Google Docs) in Firefox, I get a "Would you like install {whatever}" popup from Ubuntu. My options are only yes, "not now" and "don't ask me again."

I don't see any way to get more information about these installations. I can't quite tell if they'd be browser plugins or regular applications  (the Ubuntu icon suggests the latter) and I don't see any indication that I can get more information about one of these applications before I install it.

I'm hesitant to click "yes" just to see what happens.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a big fan of them but they seem to be not much more than a glorified bookmark of the page in your launcher with some integration in the launcher. I think they are called 'webapps' so you can find some more general info on them, for example in [this link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/list-of-that-websites-support-unitys-new-web-apps-feature)

Comment: And indeed, the webapps preferences are in Firefox's preferences. I just didn't recognize them.